# Moved drupal 7 site to new domain, white screen of death

Tags: installation, wsod

I've recently moved a drupal site to a different hosting section on the same server, the new site is under a different domain. If I edit settings.php to the new database settings, the site white screens and no errors are reported.

However, if I place the old settings.php in then the site works perfectly. I think the new domain affects the move obviously but I'm not sure how?

Comment: did you turn on `php_value display_errors true` in htaccess? Your getting errors someplace :/ I always use this blog post to help configure errors via htaccess, or logging PHP errors to a file: http://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/

Comment: I've just tried that, thanks. Unfortunately, it hasn't worked and there's still no errors, just a white screen. Nothing shows in the error log either.

Comment: Why don't you diff the old and new settings.php and replace differences step by step and see where it goes wrong. Also these post could be useful http://drupal.org/node/158043 and http://drupal.org/node/482956

Comment: Did you follow all of the debug steps on http://drupal.org/node/158043?  Without doing that you are shooting in the dark.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you clear out the cache tables? Alternatively drush cache-clear all